# Is there a reason for the inconsistent datatype overflow handling of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

I would like to know what the reasoning could be for inconsistent way sql server handles type overflowing. And what would be the proper way to prevent the *silent* data corruption SQL Server inflicts on us.

### The well behaved `int`

An int for example gives a proper overflow exception

```
declare @b int = 123456789000
```

> ```
> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
> ```

### The Silent `bit`

A bit value will be zero for zero and one for everything else you try to put in (with a little extra fun on an empty string).

```
declare @a bit = 123
      , @b bit = ''
select a = @a, b = @b
```

output:

> ```
> a     b
> ----- -----
> 1     0
> ```

```
create table #bit_type(a bit) 
insert into #bit_type values (123), ('')
select * from #bit_type
```

output:

> ```
> a
> -
> 1
> 0
> ```

```
declare @bit_type table (a bit)
insert into @bit_type values (123), ('')
select * from @bit_type
```

output:

> ```
> a
> -
> 1
> 0
> ```

This behavior is often the cause of *very* hard to debug ETL problems (invalid value in an input file is silently converted to a 1 or a zero)

### The schizophrenic `varchar`

Varchar (and `char`/`nchar`/`nvarchar`) is another highly annoying datatype

```
declare @c varchar(5)
select @c = '123456789'
print @c
```

The result is silently truncated.

> 12345

```
create table #varchar_type(a varchar(5)) 
insert into #varchar_type values ('123456789')
```

Here we get a proper overflow error.

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>      String or binary data would be truncated.
>      The statement has been terminated.

```
declare @varchar_type  table(a varchar(5)) 
insert into @varchar_type values ('123456789')
```

Here we get a proper overflow error as well.

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 2
>      String or binary data would be truncated.
>      The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I feel your pain. Rounding is not consistent as well - some types round up, some round down. Be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `BIT`

SQL is assuming that **ANY** numeric value is `'TRUE'`, while an empty string or 0 is `'FALSE'`.

The best way to handle this is through filtering in your code, i.e.:

```
DECLARE @b BIT
DECLARE @v char(4) = '1234'

SET @b = (CASE WHEN @v = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

SELECT @b
```

### `Varchar`

SQL doesn't consider `@variables` as mission-critical as tables.  The overflow error on tables **can** be disabled as well [by using the `SET ANSI WARNINGS OFF` command.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx)

I think the designers also assumed that if you are declaring a variable with a length, you will handle checking the length of that variable yourself.  Other reasons could include:

- You are setting the length of the variable (it's not automatic for the most part)
- You are specifying the input
- Ergo, you should know if your input will possibly overflow, and you will check for it if necessary

**This is different for a string than an int since a string can still be useful when truncated, while truncation fundamentally changes the nature and value of a number.**

The recommended procedure is similar to that for bit:

```
DECLARE @v varchar(10)
DECLARE @str varchar(25) = 'This is a longer string'

IF LEN(@str) <= 10
    SET @v = @Str
ELSE RAISERROR('Invalid string length!', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

Comment: bit is true for any *numeric* value. I still believe it is a bad design decision which is quite error prone. BCP for example will also quietly pump data in a bit column. Good point about `SET ANSI WARNINGS OFF` I just wish variables would follow this setting as well

Comment: The varchar variables are especially tricky when concatenating strings in dynamic sql for example. (I know, less an issue with `varchar(max)`)

Comment: @Filip - `bit` also responds to the strings `TRUE` and `FALSE`

Comment: @filip - all the more reason to validate your inputs

Comment: I put check constraints on all bit columns for now.